# Trying to verify user input with array data

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I have a class project to accomplish regarding a multiple choice exam. I have created the program code for the exam itself, but now we are required to display an error message if an incorrect input is entered. I have tried so many different ways to accomplish this and had no results. I have posted my entire program so that you can see where I went with it. I know that I am missing something. And yes, I do understand that some beginner classes and tutorial would greatly increase my knowledge, but as I am doing that; any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
 using System;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 namespace Checkpoint_III
 {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] questions =            //these are the questions for the quiz
        {
            "1)  On which day was the United States Marine Corps born?",
            "2)  Where was the Marine Corps founded?",
            "3) Robert Mullen was the first Marine Corps Recruiter.",
            "4)  Who was the Grand Old Man of the Marine Corps?",
            "5)  Marines are also referred to as “Devil Cats.”",
            "6)  Who was the first Commandant of the Marine Corps?",
            "7)  What is the Mascot of the Marine Corps?",
            "8)  The Blood Stripe worn by Marines is to signify the blood shed during the Battle of Chapultepec.",
            "9)  What is the Marine Corps motto?",
            "10)  Marines have often been referred to as “Leathernecks” due to the high leather collars worn to combat sword slashes."

        };

        string[] answers =          //these are the selections for each of the questions
        {
            "   a)   10 November 1776\n   b)   4 July 1776\n   c)   10 November 1775\n   d)   8 December 1777\n",
            "   a)   The White House, Washington D.C.\n   b)   Tuns Tavern, Philadelphia, PA\n   c)   Marine Corps Base Quantico, VA\n   d)   MCRD Parris Island, Beaufort, SC\n",
            "   True\n   False\n",
            "   a)   Archibald Henderson\n   b)   Chesty Puller\n   c)   Samuel Nichols\n   d)   Dan Daly\n",
            "   True\n   False\n",
            "   a)   Chesty Puller\n   b)   Samuel Nichols\n   c)   Ophae Mae Johnson\n   d)   None of the above\n",
            "   a)   Pitbull\n   b)   Rottweiler\n   c)   English Bulldog\n   d)   German Shepard\n",
            "   True\n   False\n",
            "   a)   “Be Prepared”\n   b)   “Do a Good Turn Daily”\n   c)   “Semper Fidelis”\n   d)   None of the above\n",
            "   True\n   False\n",

         };

        string[] correctanswer =            //these are the correct answers for the questions
        {
           "c",
           "b",
           "t",
           "a",
           "f",
           "b",
           "c",
           "t",
           "c",
           "t"
       };

        string[] validanswer =              //These are the valid inputs accepted to not recieve error message
        {
            "a b c d t f A B C D T F"                
        };



        int score = 0; //The initializing of the score board. Player starts at 0 while each question is worth 10 points. Final score will be out of 100.

        int[] questionsIncorrect = new int[10];

        //This is the beginning of my quiz program

        Console.WriteLine("Jon Smith");
        Console.WriteLine("Classwork");
        Console.WriteLine("CP4\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Marine Corps History Quiz\n");
        Console.WriteLine("There are a series of multiple choice and true/false questions\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Input the letter of the selection for multiple choice");
        Console.WriteLine("For true/false, enter t or f\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Shall we begin?");

        Console.WriteLine();
        int j = -1;
        string check;
        Console.WriteLine("Round One");


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Q{0}", questions[i]);
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", answers[i]);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Answer :: ");
            check = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Begin error message code
            if (check.Equals(validanswer))
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
                }
            while
                (check.Equals(validanswer) == false);

            //End error message code

            if (check.Equals(correctanswer[i]))


            {
                score = score + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;

                questionsIncorrect[j] = i;

            }
        }
        int k;
        if (j > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Round II");
            for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
            {
                k = questionsIncorrect[i];
                System.Console.WriteLine("Q{0}", questions[k]);
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", answers[k]);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Answer :: ");
                check = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (check.Equals(correctanswer[k]))
                {
                    score = score + 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Correct Answer is {0}", correctanswer[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Score is {0}%", score);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

   }
```

Comment: This could all be clearer if you'd create a new class to represent each question. It would include the question text and the correct answer and the list of possible answers. Then you wouldn't have to use the index number to keep track of which answers belong to which questions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you want to get a better response instead of posting your entire code and asking for debugging help, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason just a guess but the OP may not yet have learnt classes in class. Yes, pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Checkpoint_III
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] questions =            //these are the questions for the quiz
            {
"1)  On which day was the United States Marine Corps born?",
"2)  Where was the Marine Corps founded?",
"3) Robert Mullen was the first Marine Corps Recruiter.",
"4)  Who was the Grand Old Man of the Marine Corps?",
"5)  Marines are also referred to as “Devil Cats.”",
"6)  Who was the first Commandant of the Marine Corps?",
"7)  What is the Mascot of the Marine Corps?",
"8)  The Blood Stripe worn by Marines is to signify the blood shed during the Battle of Chapultepec.",
"9)  What is the Marine Corps motto?",
"10)  Marines have often been referred to as “Leathernecks” due to the high leather collars worn to combat sword slashes."
};

            string[] answers =          //these are the selections for each of the questions
            {
"   a)   10 November 1776\n   b)   4 July 1776\n   c)   10 November 1775\n   d)   8 December 1777\n",
"   a)   The White House, Washington D.C.\n   b)   Tuns Tavern, Philadelphia, PA\n   c)   Marine Corps Base Quantico, VA\n   d)   MCRD Parris Island, Beaufort, SC\n",
"   True\n   False\n",
"   a)   Archibald Henderson\n   b)   Chesty Puller\n   c)   Samuel Nichols\n   d)   Dan Daly\n",
"   True\n   False\n",
"   a)   Chesty Puller\n   b)   Samuel Nichols\n   c)   Ophae Mae Johnson\n   d)   None of the above\n",
"   a)   Pitbull\n   b)   Rottweiler\n   c)   English Bulldog\n   d)   German Shepard\n",
"   True\n   False\n",
"   a)   “Be Prepared”\n   b)   “Do a Good Turn Daily”\n   c)   “Semper Fidelis”\n   d)   None of the above\n",
"   True\n   False\n",
};

            string[] correctanswer =            //these are the correct answers for the questions
            {
"c",
"b",
"t",
"a",
"f",
"b",
"c",
"t",
"c",
"t"
};

            string[] validanswer =              //These are the valid inputs accepted to not recieve error message
            {
                "a", "b", "c", "d", "t", "f", "A", "B", "C", "D", "T", "F"
            };



            int score = 0; //The initializing of the score board. Player starts at 0 while each question is worth 10 points. Final score will be out of 100.

            int[] questionsIncorrect = new int[10];

            //This is the beginning of my quiz program

            Console.WriteLine("Jon Smith");
            Console.WriteLine("Classwork");
            Console.WriteLine("CP4\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Marine Corps History Quiz\n");
            Console.WriteLine("There are a series of multiple choice and true/false questions\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Input the letter of the selection for multiple choice");
            Console.WriteLine("For true/false, enter t or f\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Shall we begin?");

            Console.WriteLine();
            int j = -1;
            string check;
            Console.WriteLine("Round One");


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Q{0}", questions[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", answers[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Answer :: ");
                check = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Begin error message code
                if (!validanswer.Contains(check))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Answer :: ");
                    while (validanswer.Contains(check) == false)
                    {
                        //End error message code

                        check = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (check.Equals(correctanswer[i]))
                        {
                            score = score + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j++;
                            questionsIncorrect[j] = i;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (check.Equals(correctanswer[i]))
                    {
                        score = score + 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j++;
                        questionsIncorrect[j] = i;
                    }
                }


            }
            int k;
            if (j > -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Round II");
                for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
                {
                    k = questionsIncorrect[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Q{0}", questions[k]);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", answers[k]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Answer :: ");
                    check = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (check.Equals(correctanswer[k]))
                    {
                        score = score + 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct Answer is {0}", correctanswer[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Score is {0}%", score);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

}
```

Let's spot the errors in your code!

- `string[] validanswer =  { "a b c d t f A B C D T F" };`
  `validanswer` is an array with one element, therefore 
  `check.Equals(validanswer)` will never be true because the comparison you tried 
  to make is: `"a" == "a b c t..."`. I've changed the array and I've used 
  `Contains` which basically is looking for an element in an array with that value
  Same thing happens in `while(check.Equals(validanswer) == false);`
- There was a problem of `index out of bounds` because in the while loop you need to 
  read the new value. If the value is a "valid answer" the algorithm should only check 
  if the answer is correct or not
- Also you don't need to use `System.Console..`, you can just put `Console..` 
  because you already included `System` namespace

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Yes, originally I had the array with all of the strings. I had attempted to use regex to try and confirm and had seen an example of something similar. But this way works and it was something that I was very close to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are checking the variable 'check' which is a string with the content 'a' or 'b' etc. against an array of possible answers.
You can not check a single string against an array. And why are you using an array (validanswer) and then store one string in it?

You can do it like this:

```
string[] validanswers = {
            "a",
            "b",
            ...
        }


        bool isValid = false;
        foreach (var validanswer in validanswers)
        {
            if(check == validanswer)
            {
                 isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isValid)
            Console.WriteLine("The input is valid");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The input is invalid");
```

The code above is doing the same as the contains method.